# Python: Handle mspaint.exe Window returning 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, sendmessage

I'm trying to get handle on the mspaint.exe in python 3.5 but it doesn't works.

Here its the process I do and what I'm not able to do:

- I can list all windows list.
- I can get the Right title window ("Untitled - Paint")

what I can't do:

- Unable to get Handle ( if yes, the postmessage return 0 )

it's my current code

Get handle function:

```
 # trying to get handle with title parameter
 def get_window_hwnd(title):
    hwnd = False
    list = enum_window_titles();
    for a in list:
        if title.lower() in a.lower() :
            print(a.lower()) # untitled - paint
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, title)
            print(hwnd) # return 0
            return hwnd
    return hwnd
```

list windows function:

```
#list all windows list
def enum_window_titles():
    def callback(handle, data):
        titles.append(win32gui.GetWindowText(handle))

    titles = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)
    return titles
```

part of process:

```
# core
hwnd = -1
hwnd = get_window_hwnd("paint") # get handle window
print(hwnd) # 0

if(hwnd != -1 or hwnd != False): # enter here
    a = win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, win32api.MAKELONG(200, 200));
    b = win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON,0);
    c = win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, win32api.MAKELONG(400, 400));
    d = win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON,0);
    print(a);  #
    print(b);
    print(c);
    print(d);
```

The full print result:

```
untitled - paint
0
0
# here is the Post Message and Send Message
0
None
0
None
```

any Idea why I can't get handle on my mspaint?

And any Idea to know if the handle works like after PostMessage and SendMessage?

Thank you

Comment: Please don't change the question. You asked about how to get the window handle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Surely you aren't trying to draw an image by faking input? Or is paint just an example?

Comment: im trying to draw an image. I selected an arrow. and I just try to press mouse, going to X,Y , release mouse. I want in minimize or in background. so its why I try to use `SendMessage` and `PostMessage`

Comment: Faking input to paint is the wrong way. Use an image library like PIL.

Comment: its just a test for click/drag features I use paint to make sure I'm able to do that and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window's name is `"Untitled - Paint"` but you are passing `"paint"` to `FindWindow`. You do need to pass the correct window name if you are going to call `FindWindow`. Call it like this:

```
win32gui.FindWindow(None, a)
```

However, there's no point in calling `FindWindow`. When you call `EnumWindows`, your callback receives the window handle. Remember that window handle as well as the name. That way once you find the matching name, you'll have the handle already to go. Something like this:

```
import win32gui

def get_window_hwnd(title):
    for wnd in enum_windows():
        if title.lower() in win32gui.GetWindowText(wnd).lower():
            return wnd
    return 0

def enum_windows():
    def callback(wnd, data):
        windows.append(wnd)

    windows = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)
    return windows

hwnd = get_window_hwnd("paint")
print(hwnd)
```

Comment: yea I do an error. effectively. bad parameters thanks! :P I got again 0, none, 0, none in the send/PostMessage rho..